# how to confiure python with cassandra using anaconda framework?

Tags: python, cassandra, anaconda

Hello Guys I am trying to confiure the python with cassandra using anaconda framework. Please give me a solution how to configure it?

Comment: Is it the cassandra driver that you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Just install it via `conda`:

```
conda install -c conda-forge cassandra-driver
```

as described in [documentation](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/cassandra-driver).